# sort vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have following code  which  calculates peaks  and their indexes and also display them,but i want to sort peaks  value and  display so,so my code is following

```
function [peaks,peak_indices] = find_peaks(row_vector)
    A = [0 row_vector 0];
    j = 1;
    for i=1:length(A)-2
        temp=A(i:i+2);
        if(max(temp)==temp(2))
            peaks(j) = row_vector(i);

            peak_indices(j) = i;
            j = j+1;
        end
    end
end
```

which  after  implementing it by following way,it shows me  output

```
A = [2 1 3 5 4 7 6 8 9];
>> [peaks, peak_indices] = find_peaks(A)

peaks =

     2     5     7     9


peak_indices =

     1     4     6     9
```

but instead of display  peaks directly,i want to display peaks in decreasing order  ,or like this
9  7 5 2,i know  that there exist  function sort in matlab,like following way

```
b=[2 1 3 4 6 5];
>> sort(b)

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6
```

but there is two issues,first  it sort in increasing order,also how to use  sort function  in my first function  to return peaks in  decreasing sorted  form?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [documentation for sort](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) before asking?

Comment: i found it on the following link http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html,but how to use it in function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
peaks = sort(peaks, 'descend')
```

To re-order `peak_indices` respectively, obtain the sorted indices from `sort` as well:

```
[peaks, idx] = sort(peaks, 'descend');  %// Sort peaks
peak_indices = peak_indices(idx);       %// Reorder peak indices accordingly
```

Comment: no i dont want to  reorder,i want to keep it,just sorts  peak values

Comment: @dato: sorting IS reordering.

Comment: @dato: Just before the end of the function.

Comment: but if i want to keep  old  orders of indexes?for example  if i want sort  peaks,then their indexes will be changed in vector,but i want  to keep old  indexes before    sorting,how to do it?

Comment: @dato Then you reorder the peak indices accordingly like I've shown you, so that each peak index in the new vector corresponds to the peak in the sorted vector. This doesn't sort `peak_indices`, this reorders it in the same way as `peaks` are reordered.