# Sorting Data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting

I am trying to sort the following data in the Matlab, but not getting the expected output what I need.

Here is data:

```
'1B-3A-5A'
'1A-3A-19A'
'2A-2A-4A-5A'
'2B-2A-5A'
'2A-4A-5A'
'2C-5A-30A'
'11A-3A-19A
'3A-19A-42C'
'4A-4A-12A'
'19A-21A-42C'
'25A-41D'
'41C-41C'
'39C-41C'
'43E'
'39A-41D'
'1A-3A-5A-7A'
'7C-27A-28A'
```

I need the sorted list such that it considers the first number then the alphabet to sort the list like below

```
'1A-3A-19A'
'1A-3A-5A-7A'
'1B-3A-5A'
'2A-2A-4A-5A'
'2A-4A-5A'
'2B-2A-5A'
'2C-5A-30A'
'3A-19A-42C'
'4A-4A-12A'
'7C-27A-28A'
'11A-3A-19A
'19A-21A-42C'
'25A-41D'
'39A-41D'
'39C-41C'
'41C-41C'
'43E'
```

Can you please suggest a way to do it? I tried all ways but it doesn't sort it like I want. Thanks!!

Comment: I can find a lot of sort questions here on SO, but not really a good duplicate. These are close but not quite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429468/how-to-sort-property-value-pair-in-alphabetical-order-with-matlab , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222334/matlab-sort-cells-array-according-mode , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506163/sort-vector-in-matlab etc.

Comment: Yeah I tried using the matlab sort command but it doesn't sort as I want and my data is in cells.

Comment: Does the data contain only uppercase and letters?

Comment: yeah only uppercase letters and numbers and my data is either in cell format or table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [`sort`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) or [`sortrows`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html)? This does actually sort strings as well:

> If A is a string, then sort(A) sorts according to the ASCII dictionary order. The sort is case sensitive with uppercase letters appearing in the output before the lowercase letters.

As @StewieGriffin pointed out, this sorts `11a` before `1a`. Conveniently Douglas Schwarz has already produced a [code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10959-sort-nat--natural-order-sort) that overcomes exactly this problem of alphanumeric sorting on numerics first and characters after.

Comment: This is not correct, as it will sort `11a` before `1a`.

Comment: My data is in cells so it just put all the sorted data in one cell, I tried converting to table but then also it doesn't sort as I want it to be.

Comment: yeah that's the problem that it put 11A before 1A and all other also like that.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10959-sort-nat--natural-order-sort this function seems to do what you ask it to do.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works and giving the result as I was expecting. So many thanks.

Comment: I'll update the answer in that case. Please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark on the left.